Limit distribution of SDE in compact manifold and justifying statistical mechanics
Let $M$ be a connected, compact Riemannian manifold. My question is whether, for an SDE taking values on $M$, all initial distributions will converge to a unique stationary distribution.
Moreover, can this result be generalized to a broader class of Markov processes with $M$ as the state space?
For finite-state Markov chains, we know that a stationary distribution always exists (though it may not always be unique). Under certain weak conditions, such as ergodicity, all initial distributions will converge to a unique stationary distribution. Specifically, if all entries of the transition matrix are strictly positive, the chain is ergodic. A similar result holds for continuous-time Markov chains with finite state spaces (see this MO question, What conditions on the rate matrix Q
ensure unique convergence in continuous-time Markov chains?).
However, when the state space is $\mathbb{R}^n$, a Markov process does not always have a stationary distribution. A typical example is Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I believe the non-compactness of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the primary reason for this failure.
In contrast, when the state space is a connected, compact Riemannian manifold, I suspect the situation is more akin to that of finite-state Markov chains, with similar results. Specifically, when the "noise is strictly greater than zero" (I believe this is similar to the case where the matrix elements are strictly non-negative), I expect that any Markov process on $M$ will have all initial distributions converge to a unique stationary distribution.
I am not familiar with stochastic analysis on manifolds, so I may misunderstand certain concepts. Any clarification or corrections are welcome.
For the Background:
In fact, this question arises from an attempt to rationalize certain conclusions in statistical mechanics. Consider a system governed by the interactions of many particles, with its trajectory in phase space described by Hamiltonian equations, which preserve the Lebesgue measure. Since energy $H(x)$ is conserved, trajectories with initial energy $E$ remain on the level set $M := \{H(x) = E\}$, which is typically a connected, compact, smooth Riemannian manifold. Let $\mu$ be the natural measure on $M$; $\mu$ is also an invariant measure for the Hamiltonian system. However, there may exist other invariant measures on $M$. For initial measures different from $\mu$, we cannot claim that they will converge to $\mu$ as time evolves.
To address this, I propose introducing a small random perturbation, turning the system into an SDE on $M$ (as in this MSE question: SDEs and irreversibility in statistical mechanics; I think this article by Terence Tao also discusses something similar in the language of Markov chains). Such randomness seems justifiable since, even in a closed system, there are always small external perturbations. In computer simulations, randomness is also introduced due to floating-point errors.
If my initial conjecture is correct, this SDE should have a unique stationary distribution $\nu$, and all initial distributions should converge to it. Although $\nu$ is not necessarily the natural measure $\mu$ on $M$, I believe that, if the original Hamiltonian system is sufficiently chaotic, $\nu$ would approximate $\mu$ in some sense. By considering a sequence of SDEs where the noise amplitude gradually shrinks to zero, we could obtain a corresponding sequence of stationary distributions $\nu_n$ and prove that $\nu_n$ converges to $\mu$. This is reminiscent of the vanishing viscosity method in PDE theory.
Although this idea may not have much practical significance, it does help convince me of the validity of certain aspects of statistical mechanics.
